# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - Running powershell command not executed on .ebextensions

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am running this command to install web socket protocols in my AWS Elastic Beanstalk EC2 server

```
commands:
  01_install_websockets:
    command: "powershell.exe Install-WindowsFeature -name Web-WebSockets"
    ignoreErrors: false
  02_install_iis_websockets_feature:
    command: "powershell.exe Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-WebSockets"
    ignoreErrors: false
```

The command above was not executed in my server, running those script in the EC2 manually always works but doing this using `.ebextensions` does not work.

Here's the structure of my code.

[image]

And when this one is published, the `.ebextensions` is added at the root of the zip file

```
zip
   - .ebextensions
   - other files...
```

Please let me know what's missing here. I don't do any special configurations on the AWS EB.

Comment: Don't know if this could be the reason, but `leader_only` is only for `container_commands`, not `commands` sections.

Comment: @Marcin update, I remove the `leader_only` and its still the same

Answer (score 0):

I am able to run with following steps:
I am using [container_commands](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-windows-ec2.html#windows-container-commands) but, I am confident it will work with [commands](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-windows-ec2.html#windows-commands) as well.

```
    ---
    container_commands:
      "2":
        command: powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command".\\.ebextensions\\IISScripts.ps1"
```

Zip file looks like below:

```
 zip
   - .ebextensions
      - 01-windows.config
      - IISScript.ps1
   - other files...
```

**EC2 instance configuration: Windows server 2019**